# How to correctly set a big widget icon in android

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-appwidget

This is my question:
My program have 2 widgets. One of them is 4x1 cells size.
This widget has an icon(has the same width as widget itself) set in manifest file

```
android:icon="@drawable/widget_4bg"
```

My problem is that on android OS 4.x mobiles in the widget list, the icon is not spread on entire 4 cells but only in one.

[image]

How can I set correctly icon programmatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using this.

```
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_4bg"
```

sample xml **widget_info**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/your_widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="400dip"
    android:minResizeHeight="250dip"
    android:minResizeWidth="300dip"
    android:minWidth="450dip"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="172800000" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

**Update**

```
 <receiver
            android:name="com..widget.WidgetProvider"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>
```

Comment: I have tried, it didn't working. I put it into manifest file, but it generates an error.

Comment: No don't put this in manifest, rather create a new xml like i provided and set this in your meta section of the widget receiver. like now i have shown above in updated code.

Comment: unfortunately it generates error too:  No resource identifier found for attribute 'previewImage' in package 'android'

Comment: I think I found an error. My Build Target version was set to Android 2.2. When I modified it to (3.0, minimum requirements for this propriety) It's starts working. But I have another question: If I modify build target to 11 (3.0) can it affect normally working of program on 2.2 (my minSdk version is 8)?

Comment: dagha da search da aala da.dagha da bnda dekha dekha da.